# The same computation inside a loop on a constant

Tags: java

In an interface I have the following:

```
public static byte[] and0xFFArray(byte[] array) {
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        array[i] = (byte) (array[i] & 0xFF);
    }
    return array;
}
```

---

In another class I am calling the following:

```
while(true){
    ...
    if (isBeforeTerminator(htmlInput, ParserI.and0xFFArray("포토".getBytes("UTF-8")), '<')) {
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

My question is, will the resultant array from String constant be computed once during compilation or will it be computed everytime the loop iterates?

Edit: I just noticed that the method doesn't make sense, but it doesn't affect the question.

Comment: What is the point of that method. It doesn't do anything. `byte` converted to `int`, masked with `0xFF`, casted back to `byte`, will result in exactly the same value.

Comment: Under normal execution, it will execute every time. But the JIT compiler might be able to optimize it out.

Comment: Excellent question by the way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that you're referring to the result of

```
ParserI.and0xFFArray("포토".getBytes("UTF-8"))
```

Unless you explicitly cache/store the results somewhere, it'll be computed every time you call it.

You may want to consider something like:

```
byte[] parserI = ParserI.and0xFFArray("포토".getBytes("UTF-8"));

while (true) {
  ...
  if (isBeforeTerminator(htmlInput, parserI, '<'))
  ...
```

To understand why compilers don't implement this automatically, keep in mind that you can't write a general algorithm to detect if a particular method will always return the same value as you'd quickly encounter things like the [Halting Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem), so anything you try to write to do something like that would be massively complicated and wouldn't even work a good percent of the time. You'd also have to understand a fair amount about when a method will be called in order to work out a reasonable caching strategy. For example, is it worth persisting the cache after the `for` loop? You'd have to understand a fair amount about the program structure to know for sure.

It is *possible* that an optimizer could recognize that the results of a method are constant under certain limited circumstances (and I'm not sure the extent to which Java optimizers have actually implemented that), but you certainly can't count on that in the general case. The only way to know for sure if this is one of them is to look at the actual bytecode that the compiler produces, but I *highly* doubt that it's being as smart as you'd like it to here for the reasons I listed above. It's better to explicitly do the caching yourself as shown above.